# cv2.imshow only works within the first loop

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am reading image data from a camera and try to display it with openCV2. 
My GUI does the following:

- GUI with two buttons: connect to the camera and start live image display (does so in a seperate thread)
- stop button to stop the live image, joining the thread and exiting the camera connection

Unfortunately, only the first time clicking the button, an actual "live video" (more than 24fps) is displayed. After that, nothing happens (i.e. no window opens, not even an empty one or with old image data) when clicking the start button, although no error shows up.  
What I did so far:

- checking whether the program is running through all the necessary steps - it does!
- trying to display an image from the hard drive (and calling it right before displaying it) - same behaviour
- trying to display the images without multithreading - it works!

This leads me to the conclusion, there must be some issue with `cv2.imshow(...)` and multithreading. Do you have an idea, what this problem could be?

Here are the code snippets of the GUI (`.pack` excluded):

```
startLiveBtn = tk.Button(self, text = "start Live image", command = self.cam.startLiveImg)
stopBtn = tk.Button(self, text = "stop live img", command = self.cam.stopLiveImg)
```

Live image display start and stop:

```
def showLiveImg(self):
    while self.do_run:
        self.extractImg()
        self.showImg()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            self.stopLiveImg()

def startLiveImg(self):
    self.do_run = True
    self.live_img_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.doLive, daemon = True)
    self.live_img_thread.start()

def stopLiveImg(self):
    self.do_run = False
    try:
        self.live_img_thread.join()
    except:
        print("could not join thread, assume you pressed q")
    self.freeImgMem()
    self.exitCam()
```

Getting the data from camera and displaying it in an openCV window:

```
def extractImg(self):
    self.array = ueye.get_data(self.pcImageMemory, self.width, self.height, self.nBitsPerPixel, self.pitch, copy=False)
    self.frame = np.reshape(self.array,(self.height.value, self.width.value, self.bytes_per_pixel))
    self.frame = cv2.resize(self.frame, (0, 0), fx = self.windowSize, fy = self.windowSize)

def showImg(self):
    cv2.imshow("ueye camera", self.frame)
```

I am not sure if this code is sufficient to find an error. I can post more if you need.

Thank you!

Comment: some resources: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/video_threaded.py and https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8407. Using waitKey will probably be an issue. There's quite a few resources on this. Have you check them out?

Comment: I was able to narrow down the issue: it seems like ``imshow`` needs ``waitkey``  not only to display the image, but also close the image. Yet, my second thread (the live video) is being closed without using the ``waitkey`` function. Seems like there is no workaround for this instead of not using ``openCV``. Will edit my question for clarification

Comment: I just googled a bit and it seems impossible with openCV. Should I delete my question or edit it and/or answer it myself?

Comment: You can leave the question.

Comment: You can still use OpenCV, just use something else for the GUI if that's what you need

Comment: I find it a little odd though. I'm not a python guy but I had a program in C++ which would grab a frame from my camera, process it and then display it using imshow. I had to thread this entire process, because the processing meant I wasn't updating the gui every possible frame so it became every few frames. Does that differ from what you are trying to do? I just kept a window open and then updated it when necessary. I used waitKey(1) I think just for a slight delay. I could then close the display by using destroyWindow().

Comment: No, I think you did basically the same as I am trying to do, but apparently you need the waitkey function at the end of the image display. Yet, my button (on a different thread than the live image loop) calls a function to stop the thread and doesn't call the waitkey() function. Even when I tried calling the waitKey(), I suppose its not working since the live image happens on a different thread.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Imshow is really not meant to be used for these sort of things. I've read multiple times that imshow is really only meant to be used for debugging processes. It wasn't designed for complex gui applications. I've usually seen QT recommended.